# What do PhD admission officers look for when evaluating an undergraduate thesis? (CS)

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

**Background:**

- Undergrad CS Student (Junior year)
- I have a few problem statements in mind for my undergrad thesis.

I have 2 semi-novel ideas (extension works) and 1 novel Idea for my undergrad thesis. All 3 will be separate chapters. ***I mostly won't be able to complete my experimentation for the novel idea before sending out my applications (for PhD CS in The US)*** and the ***other 2 will likely be only accepted in b-tier conferences.***

**Main question:** Is that okay for an undergrad thesis? Do doctoral admissions committees expect only tier-1 conference work?

Other notes:

- All 3 papers, I am the first author but there will be 3 other authors.
- It only indirectly aligns with my interests which ill will be mentioning in my SOP for the PhD Application.
- I have done (and am doing) other major projects. The sole purpose of this work was to carry forward with my interest.

Comment: This is extremely dependent on the department and university to the point of like asking how long and on what topic a nonfiction book should be. Is there a reason you can't look at undergraduate theses written in recent years, ask some of your student friends (or contact some who have recently graduated), or ask faculty in the department? *(moments later)* Maybe the problem is that it not clear who "they" are in "*Do they expect only*". I assumed this was your own department, but in reading again it occurs to me that it might be the graduate departments receiving your application.

Comment: Incidentally, I think the reason I initially understood "they" as referring to your department is that my experience (probably dated) is that only a small percentage of applicants to a graduate program would have written an undergraduate thesis, since many (U.S.) colleges and universities do not have this possibility.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, I think "they" refers to doctoral admission committees evaluating the OP's work, not the local department/professors.

Comment: @Buffy Yes you are right, I mean "they" as "doctoral admission committees evaluating the OP's work". But thank you Dave, That was quite insightful!

Comment: @Aymous I edited your question to clarify "they" as this was **very** unclear. You haven't even referred to the entity you mean by "they" at the point you use it. If you are asking generally about how *admissions committees* view contents of an undergraduate thesis (that is, how will it contribute to a candidate being viewed favorably) compared to how *your undergraduate institution* views contents of an undergraduate thesis (that is, will it be considered an acceptable thesis for some graduation requirement etc) then I strongly recommend you make your question clear on this point.

Comment: The question itself is unclear as well. Perhaps it should say something to the effect of: "What do PhD admission officers look for when evaluating an undergraduate thesis?"

Comment: Sorry about making that unclear, I will edit out the main topic to make it more clear for future readers, thank you all for taking your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that *significant* research at the undergraduate level is pretty rare, especially if it can be completed and published.

The problem is that there is seldom time enough to get the needed background and also follow up to completion on a significant problem. Research is really open ended, especially in time. It is why some doctoral students take much longer than others to complete.

If you are diving into the unknown on a research question then it is impossible to foretell where or when you will wind up.

For that reason, I think that pretty much any research experience at the undergraduate level will impress a doctoral admissions committee in the US. This would even be true if there are no publication (yet) but perhaps many interesting questions still to be answered.

What is acceptable to your own institution is, of course, up to them, but I doubt, given what you say, that you are likely to leave too many admissions folks unimpressed.

Comment: I agree that any type of publication or research as an undergraduate will impress future institutions.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it really cleared any doubt I had. I was only asking in terms of a PhD admission committee. My university's department has their respective guidelines so I'll follow that!